# Possible to evaluate an if block to more than just true or false in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, handlebars.js, meteorite

I have a helper function for a meteor template and would ideally like to have 3 different outcomes appear. One for a correct outcome another for an inccorect outcome and one if the user denies access for the browser to access it location, see below:

```
Template.header.created = function() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback,error_callback);

function success_callback(p){
    // Building Latitude = 51.522206
    // Building Longitude = -0.078305
    var lat = parseFloat(p.coords.latitude);
    var lon = parseFloat(p.coords.longitude);

  if( lat >= 51.521606 && lat <= 51.522606 && lon >= -0.078805  && lon <=  -0.077705 ) {
    Session.set("locationCheck",true);
  } else {
    Session.set("locationCheck",false);
  }
}

function error_callback(p){
     Session.set("locationCheck",false);
}
}
```

As you can see it depends on whether the callback is successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass more than boolean logic from a function, you should probably use a string or a number return. this can be acheived by:

```
Template.header.created = function() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success_callback,error_callback);

function success_callback(p){
// Building Latitude = 51.522206
// Building Longitude = -0.078305
var lat = parseFloat(p.coords.latitude);
var lon = parseFloat(p.coords.longitude);

if( lat >= 51.521606 && lat <= 51.522606 && lon >= -0.078805  && lon <=  -0.077705 ) {
Session.set("locationCheck",0);
} else {
Session.set("locationCheck",1);
}
}

function error_callback(p){
 Session.set("locationCheck",2);
}
}
```

and work from there.

Comment: Thanks so much legacy, how do you return it into the template using handlebars?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with handlebars, but if you're going for human readability, it might make more sense to replace 0 with the string "Connection successful" 1 with "Location invalid" and 2 with "Error"

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the Boolean type to String and defines a generic helper with Template.registerHelper